# numpy matrix dot product - unexpected result

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I have a 4x4 matrix and 4x1 vector. If i calculate dot product by hand (in excel) i get different values to the numpy result. I expect it has to do with float values, but a difference of 6.7E-3 for example seems too large to just be float error? What am i missing?

Isolated code result (see below):

`[-3.24218399e-06  1.73591630e-04 -3.49611749e+04  1.90697291e+05]`

With handcalculation (excel):

`[-1.04791731E-11  7.08581638E-10 -3.49611670E+04  1.90697275E+05]`

The input values for the matrix are pulled from code, where i do the same evaluation. There, result is:

`[-2.09037901e-04  6.77221033e-03 -3.49612277e+04  1.90697438e+05]`

isolated input values:

```
import numpy as np

arrX1 = np.array([
[-2.18181817e+01, 1.78512395e+03,-5.84222383e+04, 7.43555757e+05],
[ 8.92561977e+02,-6.81592780e+04, 2.07133390e+06,-2.43345520e+07],
[-9.73703971e+03, 6.90444632e+05,-1.96993992e+07, 2.21223199e+08],
[ 3.09814899e+04,-2.02787933e+06, 5.53057997e+07,-6.03335995e+08]],
dtype=np.float64)

arrX2 = np.array([0,-1.97479339E+00,-1.20681818E-01,-4.74107143E-03],dtype=np.float64)

print (np.dot(arrX1, arrX2))  
#-> [-3.24218399e-06  1.73591630e-04 -3.49611749e+04  1.90697291e+05]
```

Comment: The max representable value for 64 bit float is huge = ```1.7976931348623157e+308```

Comment: Show the code “where i do the same evaluation”. In the code that prepares the values of the matrix, print the numbers with full precision, at least 15 significant digits. Note that you are using only nine significant digits in the Python/numpy source code, so that causes errors. How do you get the numbers into Excel? Are you pasting only nine digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at a guess this is because you're pulling your values out from Excel with too little precision.  the values in your question only have 9 significant figures, while the 64 bit floats used in Excel and that you're requesting in Numpy are good to about 15 digits.

redoing the calculation with Python's [arbitrary precision `Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)s gives me something very close to Numpy's answer:

```
from decimal import Decimal as D, getcontext

x = [1.78512395e+03,-5.84222383e+04, 7.43555757e+05]
y = [-1.97479339E+00,-1.20681818E-01,-4.74107143E-03]

# too much precision please
getcontext().prec = 50

sum(D(x) * D(y) for x, y in zip(x, y))
```

gets within ~4e-13 of the value from Numpy, which seems reasonable given the scale of the values involved.

[`np.allclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) can be good to check whether things are relatively close, but has relatively loose default bounds.  if I redo the spreadsheet calculation with the numbers you gave, then `allclose` says everything is consistent

Comment: You are right, using 15 digits input for numpy i get
```[-2.18278728e-11  1.60071068e-09 -3.49611670e+04  1.90697275e+05]```
which is really close to excel result.